# What are the differences between `Convert-Path $Path` and `(Get-Item $Path).FullName` in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, window

I'm using PowerShell to deal with some absolute path problems. I have found that both `Convert-Path $Path` and `(Get-Item $Path).FullName` can both work?

My question is, what are the differences between `Convert-Path $Path` and `(Get-Item $Path).FullName`?

I have done the following tests but find nothing. These 2 seem always to return the same things:

```
cd x:
$Path = 'x'
Convert-Path $Path
# Convert-Path: Cannot find path 'X:\x' because it does not exist.
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# Get-Item: Cannot find path 'X:\x' because it does not exist.

$Path = 'X'
Convert-Path $Path
# Convert-Path: Cannot find path 'X:\x' because it does not exist.
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# Get-Item: Cannot find path 'X:\x' because it does not exist.

$Path = 'x:'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'X:'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'x:\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'X:\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'x:\\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'X:\\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'x:\\\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

$Path = 'X:\\\'
Convert-Path $Path
# X:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# X:\

cd $Home
$Path = 'C'
Convert-Path $Path
# Convert-Path: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\C' because it does not exist
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# Get-Item: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\C' because it does not exist.

$Path = 'C:'
Convert-Path $Path
# C:\Users\user
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# C:\Users\user

$Path = 'C:\'
Convert-Path $Path
# C:\
(Get-Item $Path).FullName
# C:\
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of filesystem items the outcome is propably identical. For other kind of items (e. g. registry keys), the `FullName` property might not be available. E. g. `(Get-Item hklm:).FullName` outputs nothing, but `Convert-Path hklm:` works. So `Convert-Path` can be seen as a more generic way to obtain a provider path.